# Memory leak during SELECT TOP

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures, asmx

I have a very simple .asmx web service that returns a dataset from a ms sql server stored procedure.  The procedure returns about 15,000 records.  When the web service is called, the iis server locks up with a BSD.  One of the first things I did to diagnose was to set a limit on the number of records that were returned by changing the select statement to "select top 1000...".  I kept increasing the number to determine what capacity was causing it to break.

I found that even if I set it to "select top 20000" it would not crash.  However, if I remove the "top x" cap, it crashes every time.  I'm at a complete loss to understand how the the "top x" cap in the stored procedure prevents the crash when the same amount of records are returned with or without the cap.

I also have the exact same stored procedure called from a .net web app on the same server and it does not cause this problem without the cap.  Here's everything that I think might be relative:

The web service code:

```
[WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("soapSecurityCredentialsHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
    /* credentials check removed */
    public DataSet ESP_Export_000DS()
    { 
        DataSet dsResults = new DataSet();
        dsResults = syncBLObject.ESP_Export_000();
        return dsResults;
    }
```

Here's the interface to the stored procedure:

```
        public static DataSet ESP_Export_000()
    {
        DataSet dsResults = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(...);
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("...[ESP_Export_000]");
            sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sc.Connection = sqlConn;
            sc.CommandTimeout = 300;
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sc))
            {
                 da.Fill(dsResults);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception excp)
        {
            throw new Exception(excp.Message, excp.InnerException);
        }

        return dsResults;
    }
```

The stored procedure takes about 2.5 seconds to run.
The web service returns the data in about 5 seconds.
The IIS server is: 2008 R2 Enterprise, iis 6.1, 2 gig memory.
The SQL server is MS SQL server 2012 Web edition.

Comment: Off-topic: This `throw new Exception(excp.Message, excp.InnerException);` seems to be meaningless to me.

Comment: If your server is BSOD'ing, then it has more severe problems, **nothing** you can do in C# code should cause a BSOD (save for maybe some P/Invoke'ing into nastiness).

Comment: 1. Do you also specify the timeout duration when calling the stored procedure in the web app? 2. Do you have the stop code of the BSOD?

Comment: Just an observation,You are not closing the connections?

Comment: Have you tried to update stats?

Comment: Hey @NickOtten that was a point in the right direction. The STOP code is: 0x0000DEAD. A quick Google search shows that it is related to XenServer. The server sits at RackSpace and uses XenServer 6, so I'm pursuing it there.  Still such an odd way to trigger / not trigger it.

Comment: That might become a tough search. The 0x0000DEAD can have quite a few issues. It is triggered by a failed Assert in the Citrix code, a log of it should be stored in /var/log/messages of the citrix host. As a side note: You might want to consider moving your sql server out of 'virtual space'. MS SQL is pretty strict with its timekeeping, and virtual oscillators are not up for the job (yet). that is why I asked about the timeout in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Both @CodingGorilla and @NickOtten were right in that the problem was with the server not the code.

The fine folks at RackSpace recommended this powershell script which solved the problem.

Thanks again @NickOtten, you really got to the heart of the problem, and did so right from the beginning.

```
$root = ‘HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}’
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path Registry::$Root -Name

Foreach ($item in $items) {
if ($item -ne “Properties”) {
$path = $root + “\” + $item
$DriverDesc = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::$path | Select-Object -expandproperty DriverDesc
if ($DriverDesc -eq “Citrix PV Ethernet Adapter”) {
Set-ItemProperty -path Registry::$path -Name LROIPv4 -Value 0
}
}
}
```